# Android application preference in device setting opinion

Tags: android

How can I add application preference in device setting. I want to my preference setting be part of device setting opinion. My application setting can be appeared or displayed in device setting list.

Any API i need to use or keyword?

Answer (score 1):

You are welcome to modify the firmware and distribute it on your own line of mobile devices -- then you can add a setting to the device setting list.

It is not possible to modify the device setting list from an ordinary SDK application, however.

Sorry!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
I run the soft keyboard sample code from android developer website. It shows that if u need to activate the customize keyboard we can configure from settings->locale&text->activate the sample keyboard. But i could not find the related code to add the configuration into settings. How could that happen?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, currently there's no options on this as such. But you can maintain your application settings activity within your application itself.

You can use or create new keys to use content Provider values from System Settings so that you can store/access your settings even from other applications.